# Nested_form gem not working with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

This is my nested_form:

```
..
...
 54   <div>
 55     <h2> Address </h2>
 56     <%= f.fields_for :address do |address_form| %>
 57       <%= address_form.text_field :country %>
 58     <% end %>
 59   </div>
 60
 61   <div>
 62     <h2> Participants </h2>
 63     <%= f.fields_for :participants do |participant_form| %>
 64       <%= participant_form.text_field :name %>
 65       <%= participant_form.link_to_remove "Remove this participant" %>
 66     <% end %>
 67     <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a participant", :participants %></p>
 68   </div>
...
..
```

Now when I visit my model/new page it does not render any fields for address or participants.

This is my model:

```
  1 class CompetitionEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  2   has_many :participants
  3   has_one :address
  4   has_many :music_programs
  5
  6   accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  7
  8   accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants, :music_programs,
  9     :allow_destroy => true,
 10     :reject_if     => :all_blank
 11 end
```

This is my controller:

```
 16   def new
 17     @competition_entry = CompetitionEntry.new
 18   end
```

Why is it happening ? did I miss something?

Comment: Could it be that it tries to render existing participants which, in a new record, there are none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to use the `build` method to instantiate blank nested objects, so the view could render something.

```
def new
  @competition_entry = CompetitionEntry.new
  @competition_entry.address.build
  @competition_entry.participants.build
end
```

You can even use a loop to create more than one associated object. Like `3.times {@competition_entry.participants.build}`.

Comment: undefined method `addresses'

Comment: It is a `has_one`, so i believe it is just `address`.

Answer (score 1):

If its `has_one` relationship then the proper way to create is not

```
 @competition_entry.address.build
```

it is

```
 @competition_entry.build_address
```

Answer (score 0):

Into your CompetitionController use the builder like here:

```
def new
    @competition_entry = CompetitionEntry.new
    @competition_entry.build_address
    @competition_entry.participants.build
    @competition_entry.music_programs.build
end
```

Also, builder could doesn't know about attributes you want to transfer from the nested form into controller.

Put this into your controller.

```
def competition_entry_params

    params.require(:competition_entry).permit(<<competition_entry_attributes>>, address_attributes: [:country], participants_attributes: [:name], music_programs_attributes: [:something, :something_else])

end
```

And then use this into actions create and/or update

```
@competition_entry = CompetitionEntry.new(competition_entry_params)
```

Hope this will help.